# If we do not have gamepad with autofire, can we have autofire anyway while playing games in steam?

Tags: steam, controllers, mame

I used to play games like street fighter iv. Using autofire make it easy for me to perform some moves, like Zangief piledrive or shoryuken. That's because the actual time to press doesn't have to be precise.

Now I have two gamepad that's wireless. None of which have autofire button.

I have heard there are softwares like xpadder, however, I've heard that they do not work with either steam or mame.

I wonder if there is any software that set some of my gamepad button to be autofire that works with steam and mame?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Street Fighter IV can see xpadder just fine. The problem is it assigns all keys to player 1 and 2 simultaneously.

I searched the web. There are no options to say assign gamepad 1 to player 1 and gamepad 2 to player 2

I finally found a way to make it works though. While there is no option, the game recoqnize which player use what based on who press the start button. The first guy that press the start button is player 1 and the controller player 1 uses is the controller/keyboard that press the start button.

For example, keyboard 1 uses enter as start button.

So if I press 1, the software will assume that I want to play as player 1 with keyboard 1.

I then set xpadder to be like this

[image]

Basically I assign button in my gamepad to correspond to button in the keyboard 1 (default button) in Street Fighter IV

All Street Fighter IV concerned is that I am playing as player 1 and use **strictly keyboard**.

Now I am going to do this with 2 players but I bet the way is the same.

DO NOT press the start button of gamepad. When I do that, the software will get two button press. The start button of the game pad that is recoqnized as gamepad 1 and enter. That is, the software think I play as player 1 with keyboard 1 and player 2 with that gamepad.

So the key here is to press start button on keyboards. That means enter (for player 1) and some other button for player 2 in the keyboard.

Any other software besides xpadder is welcomed.

Comment: IIUC the game is seeing two "start" presses, one from the Xpadder simulating keyboard Enter and one from the gamepad button itself. HidGuardian can solve this by hiding the underlying HID gamepad so the application only sees the remapped inputs. Try using InputMapper 1.7 instead of Xpadder.

Comment: Would you please turn that into an even better answer?